# How to format LuaDoc multiline comments in Lua code

Tags: vim, lua, luadoc

I have a long Lua (LuaDoc) comment which I want to convert to a multi-line comment using the VIM command 'qgap'. Guess there is some solution in .vimrc with format-comments, but I couldn't figure it out myself.

Example:

```
--- This is a very long LuaDoc comment line which I want to break into many lines
```

shall become:

```
--- This is a very long Lua doc  
-- comment line which I want to  
-- break into many lines
```

Comment: One possible solution would be `:set comments=s1:---,m:--,ex:--`, but it seems a bit redundant. And how can I add it to .vimrc to be active for .lua files only?

Comment: With an `autocmd FileType lua set comments=s1:---,m:--,ex:--` in `~/.vimrc` or with `set comments=s1:---,m:--,ex:--` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/lua.vim`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. But I still think that my comments string is a bit rudimentary. For example, it formats the whole comment block and not just a paragraph within that block.

Comment: @Erwin411 That has nothing to do with your comments string, that has to do with what [Vim considers to be a paragraph](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#paragraph). If you want it to format something less than the entire comment block, using some other way of designation the target for `gq` (motion command, visual selection, etc.)